# Pagination in Ext JS Grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have to create a grid with pagination. The json data needed for the store will get in an ajax call. Here I created store and it is loaded with the data returned from ajax call.
But the grid displaying all the data returned. I have to limit it into 5 for each page.

I tried the following code,

```
      var store= new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        autoLoad    : {params: {start: 0, limit: 5}},
        totalProperty   : recordCount,
        sortInfo    : { field: "POS", direction: "ASC" },
        idProperty  : 'POS',
        data        : {},
        fields      : [
                        {'name' : 'POS'},
                        {'name' : 'NUM'}, 
                        {'name' : 'TIT'},
                        {'name' : 'MEN'},
                        {'name' : 'EIH'},
                        {'name' : 'WAE'},
                        {'name' : 'PRI'},
                        {'name' : 'LIF'}], 

    });

    var adrConn = $.getJSON('ajax.cfm', $.extend(test, {
        }), function(r) {   
            activeData = r.DATA;
            store.loadData(activeData);
            }
    );

    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
          title         : '&raquo; test',
          applyTo       : 'panel',
          width         : 1000,
          loadMask      : false,
          autoHeight    : true,
          viewConfig    : {
                emptyText   : 'No data to display'
          },             
          tbar          : mainGridToolbar,
          bbar          : new Ext.PagingToolbar({
                  store         : store,
                  displayInfo   : true  
          }),
          store         : store,
          columns: [
                {header: "1", width : 50, dataIndex: 'POS', sortable: true},
                {header: "2", dataIndex: 'NUM', sortable: true},
                {header: "3", dataIndex: 'TIT', sortable: true},
                {header: "4", dataIndex: 'MEN', sortable: true},
                {header: "5", dataIndex: 'EIH', sortable: true},
                {header: "6", dataIndex: 'WAE', sortable: true},
                {header: "7", dataIndex: 'PRI', sortable: true},
                {header: "8", dataIndex: 'LIF', sortable: true}
          ]
      });
```

Any help is must appreciated...Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

By using PagingToolbar u can limit the grid size to 5
In that toolbar you can declare grid like this

```
 pageSize: 5,
```

Example for PagingToolbar is [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/grid/paging.html)!

Hope this helps you.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle te pagination in your backend too. Thats probably the reason why you get all your records. ExtJS just sends the parameters to your backend and expect it will return the right records.

In MySQL (offset = start, limit = limit, your page will be 1 here):

```
SELECT column FROM table
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I am not getting data from backend. Its actually taking from session (the data to be displayed are cart items.) Any idea of setting start and limit for the json data that i am converted from the session data.

Comment: session data come from the server.

Comment: Thank you. I have to setup paging in client side. The full data to be stored in the grid available in client side now. Any idea?